# Error when using for-loop and String array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

It has error on the second `for`  in the array `Alltext` - in the error it says that it can't find the symbol of `Alltext` and my code can't seem to initialize because of that.

I have tried placing the second `for` inside the first `for` it didn't work. I even tried to change some way like making key code for the String array.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        System.out.print("Input number : ");
        a = Masuk.readLine();
        n = Integer.parseInt(a);

        System.out.print("Input Text : ");
        a = Masuk.readLine();

        String[] Alltext = {a+" "+n};
    }

    for (String i : Alltext) {

        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

I'm expecting the output is when i'm inputting the number and text it will show all of it in the `Alltext` array.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase and are written in camelCase, i.e. `Alltext` should be `allText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the scope of `Alltext` is only inside the first `for` loop as you have declared it inside the first loop. Hence your code doesn't know that any variable of the name `Alltext` exists outside that loop.

But if you declare it outside, you wont be able to initialise the array in the loop i.e. you can not do this `Alltext = {a+" "+n};`. Arrays can only be initialised once while declaring. Use an ArrayList instead, if it serves your use case.

You could do something like below:

```
System.out.print("Total Line : ");
a = Masuk.readLine();
n = Integer.parseInt(a);

String[] Alltext = new String[n];
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++) {

System.out.print("Input number : ");
a = Masuk.readLine();
n = Integer.parseInt(a);

System.out.print("Input Text : ");
a = Masuk.readLine();

 Alltext[i-1]= a+" "+n;//i-1 because loop starts from 1

}
for(String i : Alltext){
 System.out.println(i);
}
```